# How to call a rootscope fuction in html - Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-rootscope

i have made a `rootscope` function in which I am actually logging out the user. But I dont know how to call it in a view .

My functions is

```
    $rootScope.logout = function () {
            $cookies.remove('auth_token');
            $cookies.remove('role');
            $cookies.remove('status');
            $cookies.remove('id');
            $location.path('/signin');
//            window.alert("Logout Successfully");
            $rootScope.auth_token = $cookies.get('auth_token');
            $rootScope.role = $cookies.get('role');
            $rootScope.status = $cookies.get('status');
            $rootScope.id = $cookies.get('id');
            $rootScope.keyword_auth_token = 'Bearer ' + $rootScope.auth_token; //Need to store all of them 

            $rootScope.is_loggedin = false;
        };
```

My view is

```
<button ng-click="$root.logout()">Logout</button>
```

I have tried `$root.logout()`, `$rootScope.logout()` but its not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shoud just be available on the scope, since `$scope` inherits from `$rootScope`. Try:

```
<button ng-click="logout()">Logout</button>
```

**UPDATE...**

Since you are trying to access `$rootScope` from outside of any controller, where there is no child `$scope` that inherits from `$rootScope` then the `logout` function won't be *automatically* available via inheritance (as I had previously suggested).

You'll have to declare the `$rootScope.logout` function in the module's **run block** instead. For more information on this, read the [Module Loading & Dependencies](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) part of the angular docs.

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.run(function($rootScope){
  $rootScope.logout = function () {
      // ...
  }
});
```

Now the `logout` function should be available to call like this:

**HTML:**

```
<button ng-click="logout()">Logout</button>
```

**[Sample Plunk - Accessing $rootScope where there is no child $scope](https://plnkr.co/edit/2Cgjm2Xw9cN6KwcjzveI)**

Comment: Where are you registering the `$rootScope.logout` function?

Comment: in index file where there is no controller

Comment: Ah I see, I've updated my answer, please let me know if that works.

Comment: I have similar issue as @UsmanIqbal, in my case i was calling the function inside an isolated scope... to get around the problem i used `$root.logout()` in my html

Comment: Thnx,,Your answer is saviour for me..@MatthewCawley

Answer (score 1):

```
<form ng-controller="Your controller name" ng-submit="logout()">
  <button type="submit">Logout</button>
</form>
```

Make sure you're using the right controller so it's in scope, use ng-submit to pass the function. Make sure your button is set to type "submit".